# In Android, what's better for performance: setting a transparency on a view, or adding an overlay view over it?

Tags: android, performance, optimization, android-recyclerview

I've developed a messaging app that's using a RecyclerView with a contact image for every "row". With new messages, I want the contact icon to be full color, but with old messages, I want to have the icon faded. So, I can either do it by setting an alpha on the icon to 0.5, or I can have an overlay image (that's a semi-transparent png) on top of the icon to achieve pretty much the same effect. Which way is more efficient and would lead to smoother scrolling through the list?

I should mention that the app runs on API 14+, so I'll need to make sure that whatever I choose doesn't work much worse on older APIs compared to Lollipop (or vice versa). Or, if there is a significant difference in which way works better on different APIs, I'll design the layouts to work differently for each API.

Thanks

Comment: are you sure? Romain Guy wrote a blog entry specifically stating that setting the alpha leads to poor preformance: http://www.curious-creature.com/2015/03/25/android-performance-case-study-follow-up/. That's why I was considering using overlays instead

Answer (score 0):

Try both and measure using systrace to see how long your frames take to draw. http://developer.android.com/tools/help/systrace.html

A 3rd option might be to cache the version with .5 alpha, blended with its background (so the final bitmap does not need alpha). 
Assuming people in the conversation are not many, this may give the best of both. But again, just measure and see it yourself.

Comment: I'll see what I can find out using systrace, but I was just being lazy and hoping that someone would know the answer.